# Program is ending with taking all input and not displaying anything

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

hi everyone I am trying to run the following program but after taking one input it terminates and i can't figure out why?In main function where i am taking input of no of student if i take 1 then in inputdata function it will only take input of name and then terminates without displaying  and when i take input of 2  then for first it will take complete input of student1 and for student 2 it will take name input and then terminates i even use `cin.ignore();` but then didn't even work. can  somebody help me? I am beginner in c++ and need your assistance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string name;
    string course;
    int age;
    int marks;
};

void Inputdata(Student Stu[], int size);
void Display(Student s[], int total);
int main()
{
    int num;
    
    cout<<"How many students are there: ";
    cin>>num;
    
    Student S[num];
    Inputdata(S, num);
    Display(S, num);
    
    return 0;
}

void Inputdata(Student Stu[], int size)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)  
    {
        cout<<"Enter data for student #:"<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin>>Stu[i].name;
        cout<<"Enter Course: ";
        cin>>Stu[i].course;
        cout<<"Enter Age: ";
        cin>>Stu[i].age;
        cout<<"Enter marks: ";
        cin>>Stu[i].marks;
    }
}

void Display(Student s[], int total)
{
    int sum;
    for(int j=1; j<=total; j++) 
    {
        cout<<"Information of student #:"<<j<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: "<<s[j].name<<endl;
        cout<<"Course:  "<<s[j].course<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Age: "<<s[j].age<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter marks: "<<s[j].marks<<endl;    
        sum=+s[j].marks;
    }
    cout<<"Average Marks of class"<<sum/total<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main problem

The main problem is that in C++, array indices begin at 0, whereas your code begins array indices at 1. This means if you have an array with 3 elements, the indices of these elements should be 0, 1, 2, instead of 1, 2, 3.

When you use an index that goes past the bound of an array, your program can crash. So if you have an array of size 3, the maximum index is 2, and when you use 3 as an index, your program can crash (or worse, not crash and instead giving you some random value read from memory).

For this reason, you should replace this `for` loop in the method `Inputdata`:

```
for(int i=1; i<=size; i++)
```

with

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
```

The same also applies to the `for` loop in the method `Display`. With these fixes, your program should compile and run without crashes.

### Side problem

In your `Display` method, the calculation of the average mark is incorrect.

- In the `for` loop, you use the following code for updating the `sum` variable: `sum=+s[j].marks;`. What this means is "Set `sum` to be `+s[j].marks`". This does not add the value of `s[j].marks` to `sum`, but only overrides the value of `sum` with `s[j].marks`. So instead you should use `sum += s[j].marks`, which is short-hand for `sum = sum + s[j].marks`.
- The `sum` variable is not initialized. If you have a variable like `int sum;` and then update this variable with `sum += some_value`, this can create unexpected results. If `sum` has not been assigned an initial value, it is possible it holds some random value that was stored at the same memory location by a previous part of the program. For this reason, you should always ensure that your variables are initialized, e.g. with `int sum = 0;`.
- The `sum` variable is of type `int`. This creates a problem at the end, when you want to calculate the average. The data type `int` can only represent whole numbers, whereas the average is likely to be in between two whole numbers. So for example if `sum` is `3` and `total` is `2`, then `sum/total` is `1`, because `int` cannot represent the actual result `1.5`. To fix this, you should use e.g. `double` instead of `int`. A `double` can correctly represent `1.5`. So your declaration should be e.g. `double sum = 0.0;`.

With those fixes, your `Display` method would then look like this:

```cpp
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int j=0; j<total; j++) 
    {
        // ...
        sum+=s[j].marks;
    }
    cout<<"Average Marks of class "<<sum/total<<endl;
```

### Additional notes

To give you some more feedback on your code: In your `main` method you declare `Student S[num];`, where `num` is a variable read from `std::cin`. This is known as a "variable-length array" (VLA). While your compiler might accept this code, it is not valid C++ code in the strictest sense. If you compile your program with maximum warnings enabled, the compiler should give you the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'S' [-Wvla]
   22 |     Student S[num];
      |             ^
```

I would recommend to use `std::vector` instead. Here is how your code would look with `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
  string name;
  string course;
  int age;
  int marks;
};

void Inputdata(std::vector<Student> &Stu) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < Stu.size(); i++) {
    cout << "Enter data for student #:" << i << endl;
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin >> Stu[i].name;
    cout << "Enter Course: ";
    cin >> Stu[i].course;
    cout << "Enter Age: ";
    cin >> Stu[i].age;
    cout << "Enter marks: ";
    cin >> Stu[i].marks;
  }
}

void Display(const std::vector<Student> &s) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (size_t j = 0; j < s.size(); j++) {
    cout << "Information of student #:" << j << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << s[j].name << endl;
    cout << "Course:  " << s[j].course << endl;
    cout << "Enter Age: " << s[j].age << endl;
    cout << "Enter marks: " << s[j].marks << endl;
    sum += s[j].marks;
  }
  cout << "Average Marks of class " << sum / s.size() << endl;
}

int main() {
  int num;

  cout << "How many students are there: ";
  cin >> num;

  std::vector<Student> S;
  S.resize(num);
  Inputdata(S);
  Display(S);

  return 0;
}
```

The reason for this goes into some finer details of C++. If have just begun with C++ and you do not care about the finer details, I would say it is fine to skip over this.

Basically there are different kinds of memory, the stack and the heap ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)). The stack holds information about which methods have been called, what parameters have been passed to the methods, and which local variables have been used. The heap can hold arbitrary blocks of data. Typically the stack is much smaller than the heap. Variable-length arrays (and also static-length arrays) are allocated on the stack, whereas `std::vector` allocates memory on the heap. For this reason, `std::vector` is a better choice when the number of entries you want to store in the array can be very large.

Another reason for favoring `std::vector` over variable-length arrays would be the helper functions provided by `std::vector`. For example, `std::vector` provides a helper function for obtaining the size of the array, whereas for variable-length arrays, you have to pass the length along with the array to the methods where you want to work with the array. Therefore, using `std::vector` allows you to write simpler code.